# What is the difference between the many options given by "Texmaker" to run a script?

Tags: xetex, compiling, texmaker, asymptote

I always run with "Quick build" and it works good.
I wonder what is the usefulness of the other options like "LaTex", "Dvi->PS", "PDFLaTex","XeLaTex" etc.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Many of the options given in that menu refer to TeX engines. LaTeX will run pdflatex in DVI mode, PDFLaTeX runs pdflatex in PDF mode, XeLaTeX runs xelatex and LuaLaTeX runs lualatex. So basically these are the options running engines like xetex with a preloaded LaTeX format.

On the other hand there are "helper" tools. "DVI->PS" for example will help you if you generated a DVI file with LaTeX and want to have a postscript (e.g. for easier printing). "PS->PDF" does also call a converter, in this case from postscript to PDF.

And there are some special applications that do not directly act on a TeX file. BibTeX will work on the auxiliary files and a bib file to translate it into an automated bibliography environment. MakeIndex will generate a sorted index, again from an auxiliary file which is output by the first TeX run. Tools like Asymptote or Metapost are even less related to the TeX run itself, but compile files with their own syntax (basically graphics).

Last, but not least, there are tools like LaTeXmk which call different compilation steps automatically, e.g. running pdflatex twice to generate valid links. The only "special entry" is Quick Build which acts according to the settings (may contain one command, may contain many).